# Object not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following connection string in the web.config file, when I run I get an error

> "Object not set to an instance of object"

at the following line. I am using sql server 2012 db and visual studio 2010.

```
dbConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnection" connectionString="Data Source=sag-pc\;Initial Catalog=BalloonShop;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Is it only one project or multiple projects?

Comment: Is web.config in your same project?

Comment: Are you inserting the correct `using` on the file you are having this problem?

Comment: Is your `<connectionStrings>` section inside the `<configuration>` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Config :

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="myConnection" value="Data Source=sag-pc;Initial Catalog=BalloonShop;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pwd;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In Code :

string _connection=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnection"].ToString();

Comment: The the error is "Unrecognized attribute 'providerName'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @ayha...   <add key="myConnection" value="Data Source=sag-pc;Initial Catalog=BalloonShop;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pwd;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ToString()
```

Comment: check if your config file is in the same project